# Convert fisheye videos to equirectangular videos

Tags: conversion, 360video

My goal is to quickly create equirectangular videos from full-frame fisheye videos with a given hfov. Panoramatools, especially mpremap allow that but it takes long for each single picture. Given that gpu and 8-core cpu can be used, which program can do that quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily in After Effects. Import your footage/images, create a new composition that matches your footage/images specifications and then apply Optics Compensation (Effect> Distort > Optics Compensation.
Tweak Field of View values until you have the desired result. In some cases you will need to check the Reverse Lens Distortion box.

Cheers!